# Array map, flatten and merge PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Sister
        [biological] => true
        [sibling] => Array
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Brother
        [biological] => true
        [sibling] => Array
                   (
                       [id] => 1
                       [name] => Brother1
                       [biological] => true
                       [sibling] => Array
                   )
                   (
                       [id] => 2
                       [name] => Sister1
                       [biological] => true
                       [sibling] => Array
                   )
    )
)
```

I have here a multidimensional array
I am attempting to retrieve value from *Brother* under *siblings array.*

Ideally the end result should be like this:

```
Sisblings Array 
(
"Sister"
"Brother"
"Brother1"
"Sister1"
)
```

I have tried foreach to catch the arrays but instead of returning all the siblings as intended, its overlapping the array under brothers siblings.

```
        foreach ($tree['siblings'] as $i => $sibling) {         
        $tree['siblings'][$i]->siblings = $this->getRelationshipData($sibling->id, $region_id, $sibling_ids, $member->getKey());
        
            foreach ($sibling->siblings ['sibligns'] as $j => $p) {
                $tree['siblings'][$i]->siblings[$j]->relationship = $p->relationship;
            }  
           return $tree;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to retrieve the data you need.

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($val,$key) use(&$result){
  if($key === "name") $result[] = $val;
});
```

The end result is the $result array.

Comment: thank you so much, the code is much more cleaner and more efficient on future use, especially if i am running big arrays. cheers

Comment: If your problem is resolved, please select the answer that 
best suits you by clicking the check mark next to the answer.
The question then no longer remains open in the system.